# RDP не блокировать клиента

Tags: windows, администрирование, rdp, remote-access

Из-за разнообразия ОС, не везде могу реализовать Free soft для удаленной работы.
Обычно использую Aspia, но ниже Windows 7 не ставится.
Думал написать на c# удобное приложение для удаленного доступа через rdp(типа адрессной книги и ip куда ломится, бо все ip в голове держать не не могу.)
Либо free soft манагер для работы с rdp?

Но проблема в следующем.
При подключение через rdp я выбрасываю клиента и при выходе ему надо залогиниться, а пароль мы не предоставляем пользователям(можно ли сделать удаленно подключение и по выходу что-бы пользователь остался в утечке, по типу как в UltraVNC?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammyy_Admin не?

Comment: Не достаток срабатывание антивирусом на него. + Нужна адрессная книга, два раза клацнул и попал на нужный пк. Я могу такие образом и UltraVNC использовать.

Comment: Может быть воспользоваться встроенным функционалом "Удаленного помощника", которые формирует файл-приглашение для соединения с удаленным рабочим столом пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел програмулинку.
mRemoteNg.
Выставил протокол vnc и подсоеденился,и не выкинул с учетной записи потзователя.

https://mremoteng.org/, круто то,что мэнэджер подключений для разных версий протоколов,есть исходники ,можно собрать для своих нужд.